# Is Remote Available for DIV/SPAN in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

For example, to use for the following:

```
#index.haml

%article-content{  :remote => true, :id => "article-#{article.id}", :class => "article-content", "data-article-id" => article.id }


#show.js.erb

var article = "#article-<%= params[:article_id] %>";
$('article').html('<%= j render ("article") %>').show();
```

So far, this does not appear to work.

EDIT:

Thanks to @MrYoshiji, I seem to get closer to achieving this. However, I can still see some raw JS in the browser and images do not load from the view. And, the articles *do* appear even though there is not element in the jquery selector below, so I'm a bit confused, and trying to figure it out.

```
#articles/show.js.erb
$().html('<%= j render ("article") %>');


#articles_controller.rb
def show
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {  }
    end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Do you want to AJAX load the show page of the article in a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very nice solution I saw someday but I can't find it back. I will try to show you the basics of this solution:

```
# articles/index.haml
.ajax_load.article-content{ data: { 'remote-url' => article_path(article) } }
  = 'This content will be available soon'

# layouts/application.haml
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ajax_load').each(function(index, element) {
      var url_to_go = $(element).data('remote-url')
      if (url_to_go) {
        $.get(url_to_go, function(responseText) {
          $(element).html(responseText);
        })
      } else {
        console.log('missing url for ajax-load!')
      }
    })
  })
```

This javascript will detect every HTML element having the class `.ajax_load`, loop through each and make an AJAX call to its 'data-remote-url' attribute (if exists) and load the result of the AJAX call into the HTML element itself. With this solution, you can use the combination HTML class `ajax_load` + `data-remote-url` to load in AJAX anything in your page.

Comment: What kind of bug do you get? Your show action should respond to JS with only `escape_javascript(render 'article')` because it will load the layout in the view

Comment: @LiroyLeshed should contain only `<%= j render ("article") %>`

Comment: You should not put your email address like this on public websites, they can be indexed by a website crawler and then sold to companies as a potential customer email. I recommend you to remove this email of your comment.

Comment: @MrYoshiji--this method somehow renders *raw* code! Would you mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178135/rendering-js-erb-results-in-raw-code

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not. `:remote` is used with helpers such as `form_for`, `link_to`, and `button_to`. Check out the [Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html). You cannot stick `:remote` any old place and expect it to do something.

Comment: I've been working tirelessly to achieve this using AJAX with no success, so thought I'd try `remote`. Could you direct me to a guide/post a answer how to achieve this? thanks.

Comment: Have you read the Guide (I linked in my answer)? Here it is again: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, the guide doesn't seem to show how to Ajax load a div.