# Rendering JS.ERB results in raw code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

When an AJAX request executes, `show.js.erb` renders the partial `_article.haml`.

What I want to be able to do in `show.js.erb` is to write:

```
<%= j render  'article' %>
```

Since it has a `.js` extension I am required to wrap this in JavaScript (the example above does not render the partial), so:

```
'<%= j render  'article' %>' OR ('<%= j render  'article' %>');
```

This would render the partial but with 
raw code--including HTML and JS escaping.

```
('things will go back to \"normal.\"<\/p>\n\n');
```

What's the right way to do this?

**`welcome#index`**:

```
.ajax_load.article-content{ data: { 'remote-url' => article_path(@article) } }
```

**`articles.js`**:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ajax_load').each(function(index, element) {
    var url = $(element).data('remote-url')
    if (url) {
      $.get(url, function(responseText) {
        $(element).html(responseText);
      })
    } else {
      console.log("missing url for ajax!")
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: The jQuery's `html(string)` function should actually transform the text into HTML (from the doc: http://api.jquery.com/html/). In the show action, have you tried to do a `render 'article'` as a response for JS calls?

Comment: Try using `.text(responseText)` but I am pretty sure it won't work -- eventually try `.html($.parseHTML(responseText))`

Comment: No your question is already tagged as jQuery. Maybe use a better question title, like `appending AJAX response with jQuery does not render HTML`

Comment: Yeah, JSON would be a pain to handle here. I don't know why it does not work for you, it does work for one of my project... Have you tried `html($.parseHTML(responseText))` ?

Comment: a colleague suggested something: try using `$.get(url, function(resp) { $(element).html(responseText) }, 'html');` to tell jQuery we expect an HTML response instead of JS (with this solution you don't have to use the `create.js.erb` but only `format.js { render 'article' }` in the controller)

Comment: Oh I think I get it, your view probably contains a HTML element having `.ajax_load` too, which does another AJAX call to the same view, which makes an AJAX call again, and again, and again... You'll have to find a way to no trigger the AJAX call if the request is already an AJAX call.

Comment: Yes exactly! Okay, i'll see what I can do. Would you mind giving me an idea of what the conditional might look like?

Comment: WORKS!!! Thank you!!

Comment: You have to say that you don't want the layout when the request is ajax, you can look for this with google

Comment: Can you publish the final result? I am curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer belongs to @MrYoshiji.

Ajax:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.ajax_load').each(function(index, element) {
        var url = $(element).data('remote-url')
        if (url) {
          $.get(url, function(responseText) {
            $(element).html(responseText);
          }, 'html' )
        } else {
          console.log("missing url for ajax!")
        }
      })
  })
```

`articles_conroller` renders `_article` partial directly:

```
def show
    #respond to JS
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :partial => "article" } 
    end
end
```

`welcome#index`:

```
 .ajax_load.article-content{ data: { 'remote-url' => article_path(@article) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide where you want the partial to render. In most cases, you'd grab the container on the page with jQuery and insert the partial there like:

```
$('#article-container').html('<%= j render  'article' %>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Brandon! I think the jQuery selector is not necessary, since it already knows *where* to render the partial, the only thing is that it does so with terrible escaping. What do you think? I also updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Oh, i didn't realize you were kicking it off with custom jQuery. If you were using `remote: true` on a link or button or something, you'd include the selector in the partial. In this case, I'd render JSON from the controller, not a view and then partial the JSON in the jQuery above.

Comment: That makes sense, but since I would have to add more elements to the view, such as buttons, I think rendering it as a view instead of just JSON data would be a better solution. Thing is, it seems to work perfectly just needs the escaping fixed.

Comment: Iterate over the .ajax_load items and call $.getScript(url) and remove the processing of the body. Then move everything to the js.erb view and put the selector update in there like I mentioned in the answer above.