# Appending AJAX response with jQuery does not render HTML

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use `.html()` without it rendering *raw* html code? If not, what would be a good alternative?

For more info about my particular case please see [Rendering JS.ERB results in raw code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178135/rendering-js-erb-results-in-raw-code).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible:

```
alert($('<div> this is the div html</div>').html());
```

here I just get the html of a div that I just created